# Hello world with TDD and continuous integration using Eclipse CDT + Jenkins + Maven

Tags: c, maven, tdd, continuous-integration, eclipse-cdt

I am moving from Netbeans to Eclipse. I am looking for a tutorial that will show me how to use the following with Eclipse:

- Maven
- Jenkins
- a C testing framework like [c89spec](https://github.com/morpheous/c89spec)

My projects are either C or C++, so any of the CDT tools (Autotools, CMake etc) will be useful.

Ideally, the hello world project will be a shared library with each function tested (TDD style)- since most of my modules are shared libs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're moving to eclipse you probably already know that you have to have the CDT ( C Development Toolkit ) plugin for eclipse to write code in C.

Maven for Eclipse is called M2E and you can its located at http://eclipse.org/m2e/ - if you're familiar with maven - getting used to it in eclipse is relatively easy.

For testing - please see this tutorial: https://github.com/xgsa/cdt-tests-runner/wiki/Tutorial

A plugin working with jenkins is described here: http://ralf.schaeftlein.de/2011/07/15/control-hudson-or-jenkins-from-eclipse-indigo-3-7/

Good luck!